# How to Convert data value filed of Dropdownlist to datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a dropdownlist control in asp.net that apear like below in html:

```
<select name=drpDate" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_drpDate">
    <option selected="selected" value="31/12/2015 00:00:00">دی 1394</option>
    <option value="31/01/2016 00:00:00">بهمن 1394</option>
</select>
```

I must get the selected date and send it to sql query . I do :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InfoDate", Convert.ToDateTime(drpDate.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

`@InfoDate` declared as `datetime` in my SQL Query ,and InfoDate saved in table like `2015-12-31 00:00:00.000`

when I run my code, I got this error :

> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: debug your code and let us know that what you are getting in `drpDate.SelectedValue.ToString()`

Comment: @Just code , 31/01/2016 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly parse date time in format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` (`hh` for 12 hour format & `HH` for 24 hour format):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InfoDate", 
DateTime.ParseExact(drpDate.SelectedValue.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

For testing:

```
string nonConvertedDate = "31/01/2016 00:00:00";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(nonConvertedDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string convertedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: There was a mistake in format. You should check again.

Comment: I use this code by I have error yet. InfoDate was saved in table like 2015-12-31 00:00:00.000. hh:mm:ss.? . what is the last part?

Comment: The last part is milliseconds, but its not in your **SelectedValue** so you wouldn't define it in **Format**. You should use break point and check if your value is really in this format or not. Additionally it doesn't matter what format you are saving in database it will be compared anyhow because you're passing a `DateTime` object from C#.

Comment: I write this : `DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(drpDate.SelectedValue.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`  and use break point in this line. `Date = {31/01/2016 00:00:00}`. date is not converted yet

Comment: Please check again with the sample code I provided.

Comment: I write this :  `string nonConvertedDate = "31/01/2016 00:00:00";
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(nonConvertedDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string conertedDate = date.ToString();

        Label1.Text = conertedDate;` I put this in page load in new page. i see : 31/01/2016 00:00:00. date is not converted yet. what is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` ?

Comment: How do you know date is not converted? Was there any exception? And `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` allows variety of formats to convert from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98782/discussion-between-farzaneh-and-shaharyar).

Comment: Try This way  DateTime.ParseExact(drpDate.SelectedValue.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)